# How to add 'switcherConfig' to a Modifier pool on Magento2

Tags: uicomponent, eav, magento2.3.2, modifier

I have custom **eav table** whose attributes I'm getting dynamically on my **modifier pool**.

But I want to add **switcherConfig**, as one of my fieldset display is dependent on a selected field value.

Can anyone guide me on how to add **switcherConfig** in modifier pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this content in my modifier pool worked.

```
'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
              'switcherConfig' => [
                    'rules' => [
                        "0" => [
                            "value" => 0,
                            "actions" => [
                                "0" => [
                                    "target" => "form.form.fieldset.field",
                                    "callback" => "hide"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "1" => [
                            "value" => 1,
                            "actions" => [
                                "0" => [
                                    "target" => "form.form.fieldset.field",
                                    "callback" => "show"
                                ],
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'enabled' => true
                ]
          ]
]
```